# Flutter - How to list out forEach() value in ListView builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am trying to list data from JSON to Listview Builder . But Flutter is giving me this error: `Column's children must not contain any null values, but a null value was found at index 0`

I tried to map each one like this inside the listview

```
alo[Index]['rewards'].forEach((k, v) {
                      Text(v['name']);
                    }),
```

Here is my full code:

```
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: alo.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {
              return Card(
                  child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    alo[Index]['rewards'].forEach((k, v) {
                      Text(v['name']);
                    }),


                  ],
                ),
              ));
            });
```

Is there any solution to this? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thing is `forEach()` doesn't return anything, you could use `map()` instead, like this:

```
children: alo[Index]['rewards'].values.map<Widget>((v) => Text(v['name'])).toList()
```

If you want to add more widgets, you could do something like this:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Column(
      children: alo[Index]['rewards']
          .values
          .map<Widget>((v) => Text(v['name']))
          .toList(),
    ),
    Text('Other widget'),
  ],
)
```

Comment: I got some of the list but the rest return this error:  The getter 'values' was called on null. How can I handle the null value?

Comment: You're returning a Card with rewards, so if there's no reward return anything else you want. So, if alo[Index]['rewards'] is not null return the Card, like you're doing now, else return whatever you want to show if it doesn't have rewards.

Comment: Can I other method instead of `map() ? Because I want to have another widgets such as text widget. with `map method I cannot add another widget

Comment: I didn't understand, with map you will return a list of any widget you want for each element of the values.

Comment: I updated my answer with what I think you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, if you don't have any rewards then you can

a) Leave an empty card

```
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: alo.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {
          return Card(
              child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
              alo[Index]['rewards']!=null?
                alo[Index]['rewards'].forEach((k, v) {
                  return Text(v['name']);
                }):SizedBox()


              ],
            ),
          ));
        });
```

or

b) don't render any card

```
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: alo.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {
          return alo[Index]['rewards']!=null?Card(
              child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                alo[Index]['rewards'].forEach((k, v) {
                  return Text(v['name']);
                }),


              ],
            ),
          )):SizedBox();
        });
```

Comment: still returning me error. I have confirmed that alo[Index]['rewards'] is not null because I tried it in initState function.

Comment: Sorry, but , are you "returning" the text items in your foreach function?

Comment: Oh, some of my rewards are null, so that is why