# How to organize the data of type `List<List<String>>`

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart, widget

I have a `List<List<String>>` from `Map<String, dynamic>`.

**Here is the code of `List<List<String>>`**
tab is an object of type Tablet Class.

```
Map<String, dynamic> demo = {'Uses': [tab.usesTitle, tab.usesBody], 'Safety Advices': [tab.safetyAdvTitle, tab.safetyAdvBody]};
```

**Tablet Object**

```
Tablet tab = Tablet(
    usesTitle:  ['Pain Relief', 'Fever'],
    usesBody:  ['Pain Relief Details.....', 'Fever Details.....'],
    safetyAdvTitle:  ['Alcohol','Kidney' ],
    safetyAdvBody:  ['Alcohol Details...', 'Kidney Details...'],
);
```

**What I Tried**

```
demo.forEach((k, v){
    v.forEach((y){
      print(y.join('\n'));
    });
});
```

**Current Output**

```
Uses
Pain Relief
Fever
Pain Relief Details.....
Fever Details.....
Safety Advices
Alcohol
Kidney
Alcohol Details...
Kidney Details...
```

**I Want Like this**

```
Uses
Pain Relief
Pain Relief Details.....
Fever
Fever Details.....

Safety Advices
Alcohol
Alcohol Details...
Kidney
Kidney Details...
```

> > Actually It's demo So just printing values. In real World, I am going to use `Widgets`. So At that time `forEach` [won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58571536/flutter-how-to-list-out-foreach-value-in-listview-builder). So solution without `forEach` needed.

**Updated**
I can do the functionality of drop-down but the `Text()` widgets are aligned one by one should be in this order.
Below this one more card with **Safety Advices** with same design.
[image]

Comment: print(tab.usesTitle.first.usesTitle); print(tab.usesTitle.first.usesBody); print(tab.usesTitle.last.usesBody); print(tab.usesTitle.last.usesTitle);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why exactly are you looking to avoid `forEach`, wherever you have array, you can also have `forEach`, `map` etc.,

Try this,

```
Map<String, dynamic> demo = {
  'Uses': [
    ['Pain Relief', 'Fever'],
    ['Pain Relief Details.....', 'Fever Details.....'],
  ],
  'Safety Advices': [
    ['Alcohol', 'Kidney'],
    ['Alcohol Details...', 'Kidney Details...']
  ]
};


List<Widget> widgets = [];

demo.forEach((key, value) {
  for (int i = 0; i < value[0].length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
      // Inside this loop, j = 0 means your Heading and j = 1 means the content
      widgets.add(Text(
        (value[j] as List)[i],
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: j == 0 ? FontWeight.bold : null),
      ));
    }
  }
});
```

Then, use the widgets array you made as the `children` to a `Column`.

This will be the output.

[image]

Comment: As I Said at last, I need to use Widgets instead of `print()` statements, Not able to create widget inside `forEach`. For just demo purpose, I used `print` here. In this case, Using `map()` is great but I am trying.

Comment: Can you elaborate your example ? Try updating your question as to how do you want to use those Widgets ?

Comment: Thx for your time, Updated the question, I added an image, I can manage the functionality of drop-down. card-body contains a `Text()` which should be in this order.

Comment: One more thing, There is not only single value is present in `demo`. Lots of `dynamic` values are present as updated now.

Comment: @ShashankGb Updated the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Yeah I too tried, Thanks Working.., I see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58571536/flutter-how-to-list-out-foreach-value-in-listview-builder). And I mistaken `forEach`  totally not for `widgets`.