# how to set itemCount in map.toList()

Tags: flutter, dart

i usually use ListView.builder but in this case im using list.map.toList() then now i need to limit the length of the item / itemCount but how ?

```
 Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: data
                .map<Widget>(
                  (e) => card(e),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
```

Comment: `Iterable.take`, for more read https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables

Comment: cool simple and it works

Comment: mind to give answer so i can accept it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - How to list out forEach() value in ListView builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58571536/flutter-how-to-list-out-foreach-value-in-listview-builder)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` loop with `min` from `dart:math` to solve this

```
         Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children:[
              for(int i = 0; i < min(3, data.length); i++)
                 card(data[i]),
          ),
```